# How to Produce a Colorized Aura About an Image and Which Resembles That Image

Tags: graphics, xetex, diagrams, pstricks, pspicture

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}

% Compiles with Xelatex
\begin{document}
%\psset{unit=2}
\begin{pspicture} %[showgrid=true]
(-3,-3)(9,9)
\psframe*[linecolor=brown](-3,-3)(9,9)
\psclip{%
  \pscustom[linestyle=none,dimen=middle]{%
    \psline(6,0)(6,3)
    \psarc(3,3){3}{0}{180}
    \psline(0,0)
  }}
\psframe*[linecolor=red](-3,-3)(9,9)
\endpsclip
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the picture

[image]

QUESTION: Is it possible to produce a fading colorized (reddish in this case) glow, an aura if you will, emanating from and in the shape of a specified image---in this case, the given red Norman Window? If so, how may this be accomplished?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-slpe}

% Compiles with lualatex or Xelatex
\begin{document}
%\psset{unit=2}
\begin{pspicture} %[showgrid=true]
(-3,-3)(9,9)
\psframe*[linecolor=brown](-3,-3)(9,9)
\psclip{%
  \pscustom[linestyle=none,dimen=middle]{%
    \psline(6,0)(6,3)
    \psarc(3,3){3}{0}{180}
    \psline(0,0)
  }}
\psBall(4,2){red}{6cm}
\endpsclip
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture} %[showgrid=true]
(-3,-3)(9,9)
\psframe*[linecolor=brown](-3,-3)(9,9)
\psclip{%
  \pscustom[linestyle=none,dimen=middle]{%
    \psline(6,0)(6,3)
    \psarc(3,3){3}{0}{180}
    \psline(0,0)
  }}
\psframe[fillstyle=radslope](9,9)
\endpsclip
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for posting your answer.